# Postgres: concatenate JSONB values across rows?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm getting grips with the JSONB functionality in Postgres >= 9.5 (and loving it) but have hit a stumbling block. I've read about the ability to concatenate JSON fields, so `'{"a":1}' || '{"b":2}'` creates `{"a":1,"b":2}`, but I'd like to do this across the same field in multiple rows. e.g.:

```
select row_concat_??(data) from table where field = 'value'
```

I've discovered the `jsonb_object_agg` function which sounds like it would be what I want, except that the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) show it taking multiple arguments, and I only have one.

Any ideas how I would do this? `jsonb_agg` creates an array successfully so it feels like I'm really close.

Answer (score 9):

After some digging around with custom aggregates in Postgres, I have the following:

```
DROP AGGREGATE IF EXISTS jsonb_merge(jsonb);

CREATE AGGREGATE jsonb_merge(jsonb) (
    SFUNC = jsonb_concat(jsonb, jsonb),
    STYPE = jsonb,
    INITCOND = '{}'
)
```

Which is then usable as:

```
SELECT group_id, jsonb_merge(data) FROM table GROUP BY group_id
```

Comment: You do not need to create the function, use `jsonb_concat(jsonb, jsonb)`.

Comment: Oh wow, you're right. So much easier. Edited to reflect that, thanks @klin!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`jsonb_each()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html):

```
with data(js) as (
    values
    ('{"a": 1}'::jsonb),
    ('{"b": 2}')
)
select jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
from data
cross join lateral jsonb_each(js);

 jsonb_object_agg 
------------------
 {"a": 1, "b": 2}
(1 row)
```