# how to get jsonb from table which contains jsonb column

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have postgres db.

```
table
id data 
1 ["a", "b", "c"]
2 ["a", "e", "y"]
3 ["d", "e", "f"]
```

how to fatten data to one jsonb array?

1 ["a", "b", "c", "a", "e", "y", "d", "e", "f"]

https://dbfiddle.uk/oHYziK8p

1 ["a", "b", "c", "a", "e", "y", "d", "e", "f"]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres: concatenate JSONB values across rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39512175/postgres-concatenate-jsonb-values-across-rows) Note you will need to change `INITCOND = '[]'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH flattened AS (
    SELECT jsonb_array_elements(data) AS element
    FROM reports
)
SELECT jsonb_agg(element) AS combined_data
FROM flattened;
```

Comment: Thanks!

https://dbfiddle.uk/kd4ExbMQ